# Is there any way to "undo" the effect of #line in C?

Tags: c, line

I am generating C code based on information provided by another file (an XML file). Certain chunks of C are included in this XML file and should be included verbatim in my generated C file. I wish to use the #line directive, so that if these chunks contain an error, the user will see the line number in the XML file that the chunk came from. For example, I wish to generate code like:

```
int main() {
   #line 35 "file.xml"
   ....
   #line
}
```

I wish to somehow "close" the #line section, I mean I think if there is an error e.g. with the closing } and that is generated by my program, the user should **not** see "error on line 36 of file.xml", that will be meaningless to them and confuse them.

For example, I could imagine a #line directive on its own (as in my example) would do something like that. But it doesn't work, and there is no such mention of any such facility in the [gcc docs on #line](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html).

Is there any such facility I'm missing? Or am I just asking for something that doesn't exist? How would you go about such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to issue another `#line` directive "resetting" to the line and filename of your original file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was thinking about that too. But that would require me to know the line-number I'm up to in the file I am generating. Possible, but surely, I'm thinking, the C compiler already has the logic built-in to output errors against lines in the actual C file, as that's what it'd do if there had never been any #line directives in the file at all. There's no point me duplicating things already built into the compiler (unless I have to?). Plus, I am just writing the generated C file to a stream, so it's not totally trivial to work out the current line number.

Comment: No - the C pre-processor doesn't provide that mechanism.  Computers are good at counting; make it (the code generator) do the work for you.

Comment: The C preprocessor can do that for you---if you use an `#include` directive.  (Look at preprocessed output to see all the #line directives generated.)